# Disable process with sc config not allowed

Tags: anti-virus, avg-antivirus, metasploit

I'm learning penetration testing and tried to disable the watchdog processes of AVG 2015 Antivirus Free on the target PC (Windows XP SP3 running in VirtualBox) with the commands:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> sc config AVGIDSAgent  start= disabled
C:\WINDOWS\system32> sc config avgwd        start= disabled
```

But I get `Access Denied` even though I am logged in as administrator. Is there an other way to disable (or even kill) a service using the command line or the `msfconsole` with `meterpreter`?

I want to disable the service so I can kill all AVG processes after the next reboot.

Comment: You might need something that could remove AVG's kernel hooks first, e.g. KernelDetective...

Comment: Kernel Detective does not provide any command line interface AFAIK. Is there another program which can do this?